# How is steam affected by a fan?

Tags: air, humidity, fan

**Scenario**

Consider a humidifier with a fan behind it. Assume same room, moderate temperature, low fan speed.

```
| |
| |
|F|               /   \
|A| >>   >>   >> | O.o |
|N|    | /\  |    \ _ /
| |    | /\  |
| |    |HUMDF|     YOU
```

**Question**

What happens to the steam? Will it dissipate quicker? Does it increase the over humidity of the room? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

The more humid the air already is, the less humidity humidifiers add to the air (evaporation rate decreases with higher vapor pressure). Without a fan, the air around the humidifier will become humid more quickly that the air far away from it. As the air around the humidifier becomes more humid, it will be more difficult to increase its humidity. Adding the fan means that the humid air around the humidifier will be replaced with less humid air, increasing the rate at which humidity is added to the air. So, yes, the fan will increase the rate at which the humidity of the room increases. Although I don't think most humidifiers produce "steam", *per se*. "Steam" implies that it's at a temperature higher than boiling, but humidifiers can work without heating the water that much.